# How can i jdbc authentication with my persistence.xml and datasource-jdbc.xml?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-security, persistence, weblogic12c

I work with : Maven, spring security 5.1.4, DB Oracle 12 and Weblogic server 12.

I want to perform a jdbc authentication with my persistence.xml and datasource-1-jdbc.xml files, How do I proceed ?

Thank you in advance for your assistance

my WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;    

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "projetSSPFDB_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;   

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="projetSSPFDB_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>DSprojet</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my datasource file is located in "..\middleware\user_projects\domains\developerSRV\servers\AdminServer\upload\DSprojet\app\datasource-1-jdbc.xml",

my datasource-1-jdbc.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source">
  <name>DSprojet</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myurl</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>myusername</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>password</name>
        <value>mypassword</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
  <jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>DSprojet</jndi-name>
  </jdbc-data-source-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

my temporary solution for authentication is  :

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myURL");
    dataSource.setUsername("myUSERNAME");
    dataSource.setPassword("myPASSWORD");

    return dataSource;
}
```